# Junit test error with Ant, no message, no reason given

Tags: ant, junit

I'm trying to use Junit test with ant.

Since I don't really know how to write Junit test without eclipse, I'll just start with something completely trivial I found online. This should always pass.

Test1.java

```
import junit.framework.*;
public class Test1 extends TestCase {
  @Test
  public void testOne()
  {
    System.out.println("Heyy there I'm a test!");
    assertTrue( "TestExample", true );
  }
}
```

I add to my build.xml these...

```
49   <target name="junit" depends="jar">
50     <junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" fork="yes" showoutput="yes">
51       <classpath refid="application"/>
52       <test name="test.Test1"/>
53     </junit>
54   </target>
```

So now when I run "ant junit" I'm getting

```
junit:
    [junit] Running test.Test1
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
```

So... that doesn't tell me anything... what was wrong? how to fix it? nothing.
Anyone knows what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce it. I was expecting `junit` to give some more verbose message, like `Class test.Test1 not found`. But no, it just fails. It means the class is not in the classpath. Open your jar file (with archivizer like `7zip` to confirm that).

And no surprise, as your class does not compile :) Add the following:

```
package test;
import org.junit.Test;
```

and your first test should pass.

Comment: @Matthew Without `junit.framework.*` it wouldn't recognize `TestCase` nor `assertTrue`. He needs to declare them somehow and this line seems to do the job.

Comment: @You shouldn't mix and match junit3 (junit.framework.*) and junit4 (org.junit.*) in the same testcase. It only confuses things. Use one or the other. If you decide to use junit4 (@Test), you don't need extends TestCase, and he should be using org.junit.Assert;

Comment: hi guys :)
It seems ant uses junit3, so it is the one w/o the annotation and the correct import would just be junit.framework.*

Answer (score 0):

@jarekczek helped me huge by letting me know that Junit is not some external thing to be compiled separately to execute but it needs to be compiled into the jar with your other source files.

The problem was that I put my test/ directory outside of my src/ directory, and when ant compiles the java files in src/ it did not compile the file Test1.java into Test1.class

I moved the test/ folder into the src/ folder, and now I got more informative error messages from the javac compiler, and was able to fix it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Evan, I suggest you have 2 independent source trees with the same package structure. `src` tree and `src-test` tree. For package `my.test` you would have directories `my/test` in both trees. That makes it able to separate tests from the application files, but from the other hand - they all land in the same package and are able to access each other. So what I do with junit is have 2 jars: `app.jar` and `app-tests.jar`. When I run tests, I provide both jars on the classpath. When I do a release, I release only the main jar. You're welcome!